# Have an error with my GMapsFX library files

Tags: java, google-maps, javafx, google-maps-api-3, fxml

I'm trying to link a GMapsFX library to an FXML file but this error keeps appearing when trying to open the actual map page.

FXML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" 
minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="602.0" prefWidth="540.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <GoogleMapView layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="602.0" prefWidth="540.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I have already downloaded the correct JAR files but I feel it may be an error with that.

Here is the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView.<clinit>(GoogleMapView.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1009)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:746)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at SignInAfterPage.SignInAfterPageController.createScene2(SignInAfterPageController.java:60)
at SignInAfterPage.SignInAfterPageController.openMapPage(SignInAfterPageController.java:41)
... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 78 more
```

Comment: Exactly the same error you get in the question before. GMapFX uses slf4j as facade for logging. But this library is not included in GMapFX. So download it and include it in your classpath or use Maven in order to download all dependencies. (requires more time at the beginning if you do not know it, but make the application lifecycle - including the use of external libraries easier- after).

Comment: Yeh I've downloaded it and added it to library but the error still is appearing, do you have any links that are more reliable?

Comment: Which library have you downloaded ? GMapFX ? Because I was talking about  slf4j libraries whose GMapFX depends on. If you talked about slf4j, which ones have you downloaded ? Even after having added slf4j libraries, you will get some extra errors because I am pretty sure GMapFX depends on other libraries and a logging library (logback or log4j for example) will be missing.

Comment: ah there are just so many libraries to download so I don't know where to get it all from

Comment: I've downloaded just GMapsFX - 2. 12.0 jar

Comment: what else should i download?

Comment: On [this link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lynden/GMapsFX/2.12.0), have a look on compile dependencies, download them, and add them to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Read the message:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

You need to add slf4j-.jar to your classpath:

https://www.slf4j.org/download.html

For new projects I sugeest to use an dependency management tool like [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [gradle](https://gradle.org/). It makes the handling of dependencies much more easier.